# Does tor browser open up 5 circuits initially?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

TOR creates 5 circuits initially. Does the TOR browser do the same?

Answer (score 2):

Tor Browser launches it's own copy of `tor`.

The tor that it launches doesn't differ from any other instance of `tor`, except by configuration differences defined in `torrc` and `torrc-defaults`.

Anything that `tor` does, the `tor` launched by Tor Browser will also do.

`tor` opportunistically opens a number circuits, Tor Browser's `tor` does too.

Comment: But the browser creates a new circuit for each unique domain while TOR's number of circuits does not exceed 5. So the browser does have it's own functionality to.

Comment: If more are needed, they're created.

Comment: But the browser creates a circuit for each new domain. TOR specifically doesn't do that - It will only do that if the current circuits can't serve a certain request.

Comment: Tor doesn't do it by default. Tor *can* do it: **Tor Browser's Tor Does Not Differ From Any Other Instance Of Tor**. See [this answer](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/12228/tor-button-api-for-extension/12239#12239) for an explaination of how Tor Browser's circuit isolation works.