# "New Tor circuit for this site" does not work?

Tags: circuit

I'm using Tor for some time now.  It seems that "New Tor circuit for this site" has stopped to work.

I use Tor to access `libgen.io`.  When Netherland is the last (before internet) node, no matter how many time I click "New Tor circuit for this site", the nodes do not change.

Have I missed something?

Comment: Interesting, I think this is a bug. I am going to investigate this further.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently a bug with Tor Browser's *New Circuit for this Site*.

The Tor Browser developers are aware of it and are working on a fix, a ticket for this bug already existed at [#22538](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/22538).

*(See [this answer](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/12239/12737) for background on how Tor Browser handles circuit isolation.)*

The problem seems to be a bug in Tor Browser accurately telling Tor Button what URL is in the address bar. It's trying to get a new circuit for the *error page* rather than the site in the URL bar which results in you re-using the same circuit for the actual page and being stuck on the same circuit (it seems they block at least one Dutch node, maybe all? any that generate and error page are likely to cause similar issues).

Hopefully this issue will be fixed soon. I'll update this answer if I see any news of it, otherwise you can look for updates on patch notes when the next Tor Browser is released at the [Tor Project Blog](https://blog.torproject.org/) or follow the ticket that I linked above.

Edit: As Yawning notes, in the meantime *New Identity* will work since it triggers a mechanism within Tor to ensure all new connections will go over fresh circuits but this will reset your Tor Browser back to a new session as well (clearing all session data, closing all tabs, etc).

Comment: In the mean time, using "New Identity" will work, because the underlying mechanism is different.  THough the UX will be horrific.